# NodeJs terminal configuration in VScode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, configuration

How do I configure details of nodeJS terminal? ( using- windows 10 & VScode )

Its bothers me that when I type commands in split screen mode, the line gets split up because it ran out of space. If possible, id like the terminal to display:
`$` 
when awaiting commands.

Answer (score 0):

1. please use the remote wsl extension for windows subsystem for linux
2. for ubuntu terminal in vs code use extension Ubuntu pastebin for vs code